# Angular Directives for Kendo: "kendo" is undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui

I am trying to use the demo items on the Kendo page in my Angular app.  Most work fine, but a few of them are throwing JSHINT errors of "undefined" objects, for example:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.showInContainer = function() {
  var date = new Date();
  date = kendo.toString(date, "HH:MM:ss.") + kendo.toString(date.getMilliseconds(), "000");
  $scope.notf2.show(date, "info");
 };
 $scope.dismissAll = function() {
   $scope.notf1.hide();
   $scope.notf2.hide();
 };
}
```

This says that "kendo" is undefined (as in `kendo.tostring()`)

This leads me to believe some code is missing somewhere.

I have included `kendo.core.min.js`, `kendo.ui.core.min.js`, `angular-kendo.js` as directed

Comment: Should you be injecting `kendo`?

Comment: You might have to inject `$window` and reference kendo via that

Comment: It looks like the kendo object is included in their commercial `kendo.all.js` but not in `kendo.core.js`. I can't be certain.  I probably can do what it does here with plain js though.

Comment: in your app.js, maybe you need to define the directives var app = angular.module('app', ['kendo.directives' ]);

Answer (score 0):

Please try this [code](https://jsbin.com/hakufipici/edit?html,js,output) to verify your kendo.version is correct in your global namespace object, "kendo".

https://jsbin.com/hakufipici/edit?html,js,output

```
$(function(){
   if(kendo === "undefined"){
     alert('no kendo');
   }else{
     alert(kendo.version);
   }
    });
```